# How to generate a private/public key pair and sign data with the private one using the Webcrypto API?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptography, webcrypto-api, webcrypto

I want to sign data, return the signature and the public key ( and "forget" the private key ). I want to use the Webcrypto API

- [`generateKey()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey)
- [`sign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign)

Based on the docs I started with the following

```
const generateKeyPair = async function() {
    return crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "ECDSA",
            namedCurve: "P-384",
        },
        true,
        ["sign", "verify"]
    );
}

const sign = async function(privateKey: CryptoKey, buffer: BufferSource) {
    return crypto.subtle.sign(privateKey.algorithm, privateKey, buffer);
}
```

Based on my tests I think the function `generateKeyPair` is fine. But when I try the `sign` function like so

```
import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";
import { generateKeyPair, sign } from "../../src";

describe("sign", () => {
    it('returns a signature.', async () => {
        const { privateKey } = await generateKeyPair();

        const data = { foo: 'bar' };
        const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);
        const buffer = Buffer.from(stringifiedData);

        await expect(sign(privateKey, buffer)).resolves.toBeTruthy() // expect signature here
    });
});
```

the test fails with the error

> Error: promise rejected "TypeError [ERR_MISSING_OPTION]: algorithm.hash is required" instead of resolving

so I guess `privateKey.algorithm` is lacking the internal `hash` field. Am I using the wrong algorithm? I also tried to add `"hash": "SHA-512"` to the options in `generateKeyPair`.

I basically want to generate a key pair and use the private one for signing and the public one for reading.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: P-384 is most often paired with SHA-384. SHA-512 also works (the hash is then truncated, see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62775)). The WebCrypto API documentation provides an [example of ECDSA with P-384/SHA-384](https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/main/web-crypto/sign-verify/ecdsa.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a name and hash for the signature algorithm to use. In the case of an ECDSA signature, you need to pass an [`EcdsaParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EcdsaParams) object to the [`sign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign) function:

```
const sign = async function(privateKey: CryptoKey, buffer: BufferSource) {
    return crypto.subtle.sign({
      name: 'ECDSA',
      hash: 'SHA-512'
    }, privateKey, buffer);
};
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUzAgTgQygg0ggngBTQEsUYBeGNCXMYGAMwFdaojwAKAShgG8BYAFAxhMFAiiMUYGMBS4ADlBAA6CIwBGUADYJliZOkw5c7QSPO8zF62DQBbBAC4YAIgCiAYQAiAZQCCLgA0Vtbmtg4AJh6SAG5OrvgAtADMABwALEEhFgC+wUKhUCiMCPmhMADaLhBEcGBBrnEoRPS4LgC62ZwA3II5vQKCoJCwNXXklNS0DMzArBzyzTEY2HjOHnKKIMaBMOqM9PSozgBCB0coPiCSwAjc-AXCYhJSMptKqhraumNg7A82ezxADknl8fmBZQsAAsqNDnMCfAAJPyJACsAEYAEzA7J5GCLIjLIx4Xb7Q6oHp9AaCdhUGh0LjkAB8lkeMnA0F4BKWK2MMByEzQAHdiLB9Kg+XhCCQuANzMMuREMGgJjwGCAQAj1GgUMCBfKRIrRkUiGA4C0iAgIl4VRMAFI+ADyADlVKbzS0TMqoGgqezjXtzqgJshhTAACoIAAeUDctBAEVQXGUSFASfY0GanvoVptKv9Cs5o1qtheCCFoqIJbq7EJxNWuDJwZQ-uyipAOmUWhAcEzpYwkjuAxynDlgiAA)